# How to add App-Webpart into a page using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to add a App-Webpart like a Custom List which is already in Sharepoint to a Page using PowerShell. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job...

```
$WebUrl = 'Your Site\Web Url'

Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"

$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl
$oWebPartPage = $SPWeb.GetFile("SitePages/Test.aspx") # Url of Page where webpart should be added

$oWebPartPage.Checkout()
$oWebPartManager = $oWebPartPage.GetLimitedWebPartManager([System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)

$list = $SPWeb.Lists["YourListName"] # Name of the list

$oWebPartView = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ListViewWebPart"
$oWebPartView.ListName = $list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
$oWebPartView.ViewType = "None" 
$oWebPartView.ViewGuid = ""
$oWebPartManager.AddWebPart($oWebPartView,"RightZone",2)
$oWebPartManager.SaveChanges($oWebPartView)
```